# How to align 2 separated lines numbers?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS. What I need to do is to align two separated lines, which can have different numbers. What I have now is:

`First line: 1,1,1,1
 Second: 2,2,2,2`

What I need to achieve is:

`First line: 1,1,1,1
 Second:    2,2,2,2`

```css
.wrap {
    display: flex; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="foo">
        <p>First line: 1,1,1,1</p>
        <p>Second: 2,2,2,2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the numbers are not aligned with each other at the moment. If I would add something like `text-align` and the numbers would change, it wouldn't be aligned either.. How to do so in CSS?

Comment: Well, in your post, the numbers look aligned in both your obtainedoutput and your required output. On a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text and numbers with spans, and use CSS to display as table:

```css
.foo {
  display: table
}

.foo p {
  display: table-row;
}

.foo span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <p>
    <span>First line:</span>
    <span>1,1,1,1</span></p>
  <p>
    <span>Second:</span>
    <span>2,2,2,2</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p style="display:block; width:130px; background-color:red; "> First line: <span style="float:right">1,1,1,1</span></p>
    <p style="display:block; width:130px; background-color:red;">Second:<span style="float:right">2,2,2,2</span></p>
```

Use display block and width to have them each in a separate line

And if you want to use flex:

```
 <body style="diplay:flex">
    <p style=" width:130px; background-color:red; "> First line: <span style="float:right">1,1,1,1</span></p>
    <p style="width:130px; background-color:red;">Second:<span style="float:right">2,2,2,2</span></p>
</body>
```